# NPM can't install node-sass on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

Having problem with installing node-sass (**all version 4.9.0, 4.12.0, 4.13.0 and so on**) on windows 10.

NPM version - **v6.4.1**
NODE version - **v10.15.3**

Problem:

```
3090 silly saveTree `-- node-sass@4.13.0
3091 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
3092 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
3093 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
3093 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
3093 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
3093 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
3094 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.13.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
3094 verbose stack spawn bash ENOENT
3094 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
3094 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
3094 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
3095 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.13.0
3096 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-content\themes\web
3097 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
3098 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-sass"
3099 verbose node v10.15.3
3100 verbose npm  v6.4.1
3101 error file bash
3102 error path bash
3103 error code ELIFECYCLE
3104 error errno ENOENT
3105 error syscall spawn bash
3106 error node-sass@4.13.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
3106 error spawn bash ENOENT
3107 error Failed at the node-sass@4.13.0 install script.
3107 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3108 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

All steps are done:
-**-force**, **-g**, **--unsafe-perm** and a lot of more, but nothing works.

P.S on my old computer it works perfect. Same node, npm version. And I also copy all **AppData/npm AppData/npm-cache** folders to new PC - but still not working.

Maybe someone was facing same problem? Maybe some permissions are missing?

Comment: install wsl on your machine

Comment: or any software that provides you with a bash shell (cygwin, etc.)

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă thanks, working perfect :) You just saved me a lot of time. You can submit your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to solve error with node-sass install script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811050/how-to-solve-error-with-node-sass-install-script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these error messages, you should install software that provides your system with a bash shell (WSL, CygWin, etc.)

```
3101 error file bash
3102 error path bash
3103 error code ELIFECYCLE
3104 error errno ENOENT
3105 error syscall spawn bash
3106 error node-sass@4.13.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
3106 error spawn bash ENOENT
```

Answer (score 0):

According to node-sass [docs](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install) you need to install [node-gyp prerequisites](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows).

Comment: did you ran `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator)?

Comment: Yes and error apears:

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\USER\.npm-global\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js

npm ERR! windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall: `node ./dist/index.js`
npm ERR! Failed at the windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall script.

I install with **--ignore-scripts** and it install successfully, but it's not working too.